# Can't get angular/Core api to download a pdf into a new window

Tags: c#, angular, angular9

I am trying to open a new tab and display a downloaded pdf from Core 2.2 web API in angular 9

```
  public GeneratePdf(id: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get( this.urlPdf + '?id=' + id, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }


 this.dataProvider.GeneratePdf(id).subscribe({
      next: (blob) => {

       const blobpart = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' });
       var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobpart);
       let win: any = this.getWindow();
       win.open(fileUrl);
      },
      error: (err) => this.error.handelHttpError(err),
   });
```

API

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("PDF")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PDF(Guid Id) {
      _logger.LogInformation("Request:" + Request.GetDisplayUrl());
      var endpoint = _appSettings.PdfEndpoint;

      try {
        var param = await _dal.GetPDFParameters(Id, endpoint);

        // Get PDF stream
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(param.EndpontUrl);

        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
          using(HttpContent content = response.Content) {
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            Stream sourceStream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            sourceStream.CopyTo(memStream);

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
              Content = new ByteArrayContent(memStream.ToArray())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
                  FileName = Id.ToString() + ".pdf"
                };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return result;
          }
        } else {
          var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
          return result;
        }
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception error");
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        return result;
      }
    }
```

it doesn't throw an error, it just opens a json object in the new tab, and the size of the object looks too small as the pdf content is over 3k bytes

{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=bd94ee98-65be-4c4f-a001-abecaf1a0644.pdf"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/octet-stream"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}

update, there was a small error on the Blob, I was not passing in the blobpart to the url.CreateObjecturl Now the app loads the new tab, but states an invalid pdf as there is no content. I know the pdf bytes are going into the content of the api result as i have checked it. and converted it to a string to ensure it's a pdf, which it is.

Thanks for taking the time too look.

Comment: maybe Content-Type: application/pdf ?

Comment: still the same result, thanks for the suggestion,

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1277819/why-does-chrome-sometimes-download-a-pdf-instead-of-opening-it